# The literal of type long is out of range

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to do some calculations for a unit converter im creating and have stumbled upon a problem.

```
out10 = doubleInput / 94605284000000000000000L;
```

Eclipse says that "The literal of type long is out of range", I didn't even think this was possible, but maybe some f you know how to work around it ?

Comment: Why didn't you think it was possible? Did you believe longs had unlimited size? longs are 64-bit signed integers in java.

Comment: Because im not used to using long and double, I don't know what their maximums and minimums are, always used int or real as datatypes in the past

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it a double literal instead of a long literal, with some loss of accuracy. Assuming `doubleInput` is also a double, and the output is as well, then there's no reason not to do that. If you need a really big integer constant with perfect accuracy, use a `bignum` (google it).

Comment: How would I go about changing this from a long literal to a double literal, as both the output and doubleInput are doubles ?

Comment: Remove the L and add a decimal point. You can also format a double literal in java like `9.46e20D` where 20 is whatever the exponent should be for that number in scientific notation.

Comment: 94605284000000000000000d is a double literal

Answer (score 5):

Type `long` cannot hold such a big value. I suggest you try type [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which can hold values of any size.

`new BigDecimal("94605284000000000000000")` 
should work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there are basically two steps involved:

- Parsing the literal to a valid value for that literal type (`int` in your example).
- Converting that value to the target type.

See the following expressions.

```
int z = (int) 2147483647; //Compiles.
int a = (int) 2147483648; //Doesn't compile, because the literal `2147483648` is outside the range of `int`.
int b = (int) 2147483648L;  //Compiles.
```

In your example, `out10 = doubleInput / 94605284000000000000000L;`, the compiler first assumes the literal `94605284000000000000000` as an `int` type which is outside the valid  range of `int` (from -2,147,483,648 to 2147483647). Therefore, it issues a compiler error.

Comment: The error message shows that the compiler inferred correctly that the number is of type long. The issue is simply that the number is too big even for a long.