# Why is one number legal and the other illegal?

Tags: java

Why are certain numbers in source code legal and others illegal?

```
class Example{ 
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(2147483647); //legal
        //System.out.println(2147483648); //illegal
        System.out.println(2147483648L); 
        System.out.println(9223372036854775807L);
        //System.out.println(9223372036854775808L); //Error
        System.out.println(9223372036854775808f); //Legal
        System.out.println(9223372036854775808D);//Legal
    }
}
```

Comment: See `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: See `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(2147483647));`

Comment: Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Because each type (int, long, float, double) has its own limited range of legal values. See also [`Long.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE).

Comment: Related: [The literal of type long is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736373/the-literal-of-type-long-is-out-of-range). Search for more.

Comment: It is probably because of the maximum value a string can be....

Answer (score 2):

When directly invoking a number with no decimal point in java it automatically assumes it is an integer (type is `int`, and it’s signed). Which has a memory space of 4 bytes allowing a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 which is why that is legal but not 2,147,483,648. When you place an `L`, `f` or `D` you're telling the compiler that the value is to be defined as a long, float or double (respectively) which have larger memory allocations allowing for larger range of values.

For more information I suggest you read up on data types in relation to java.